# Cannot authorize PHP NTLMSoapClient with MS Dynamics Great Plains ERP

Tags: php, soap, microsoft-dynamics, ntlm

Having difficulties authorizing php SoapClient with MS Dynamic Great Plains. I can connect through SoapUI. However, it only successfully connects on 3rd attempt. Also, the auth token progressively gets longer. See pastebin link below.

I made use of the following package (https://github.com/mlabrum/NTLMSoap) to setup a NTLM stream, but it doesn't seem to be sending a correct token. The token length is shorter than what is sent through SoapUI.

```
$wsdlUrl = 'http://example.org:48620/Metadata/Legacy/Full/DynamicsGP.wsdl';
        $options = [
            'ntlm_username' => 'Domain\username',
            'ntlm_password' => 'password'
        ];

        $soapClient = new \NTLMSoap\Client($wsdlUrl, $options);

        $params = array(
            criteria => array(
                'ModifiedDate' => array(
                    'GreaterThan' => '2016-04-18',
                    'LessThan' => '2016-04-19'
                )
            ),>
            'context' => array(
                'OrganizationKey' => array(
                    'type' => 'CompanyKey',
                    'Id' =
                )
            )
        );

        $soapClient->__setLocation('http://example.org:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices/DynamicsGPService.asmx');
        $response = $soapClient->GetPurchaseOrderList(array($params));
```

I had to set use ___setLocation() because client was being forwarded to http://localmachine:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices/DynamicsGPService.asmx

I have been trying to get Charles Web Proxy to work to show the actual the request/response, buts its crapped out on me.

This is the SoapUI output. http://pastebin.com/7zg4E3qD